# Multiprocessing Pool - most workers are loaded but still idle

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, multiprocessing, threadpool

In a python 2.7 script, a first multiprocessing code to process a big chunk a `numpy` array. This is basically projection ray frameblock between an image plan and a Cartesian (world) plane. That part, called `poo1`, works fine.

Further in the script, I attempt to reproduce the multiprocessing code to project a lot of images with this projection ray frameblock.

It seems that only 4 to 6 workers working but all of them is ready to work filling with data. The `pool2` creates workers, they are slow growing in memory usage, only up to 6 of them are using CPU power.

**Screenshot**:
[image: Workers that do not work during multiprocessing]

**Notes**:

- There is not output return to get from the multi-processed function, the output if a file writing in a folder;
- No worry about memory size issues, half TB available;
- No worry about the order of the process;
- Number of workers is physical CPU core - 1 = 27;
- The length of the list of jobs to distribute (paramsGeoRef) can be from 1 to 250 rows.

**Arguments info**:

- Frameclock, massive ndarray, can be GB
- A1 : ndarray, can be hundrens of MB
- A2 : ndarray, can be hundrens of MB
- B1 : integer value
- B2 : integer value
- fileName : string, name
- D1 : string, path
- D2 : string, path
- D3 : string, path
- P1 : small array
- P2 : small array

**A simplification of the code look like this**:

```
    def georef(paramsGeoRef):

        #Pseudo workflow
        """
        - unpack arguments, Frameclock, A1,A2, B1, B2, fileName, D1, D2, D3, P1, P2 <== paramsGeoRef
        - Loading tif image
        - Evergy convertion
            with function and P1, P2
        - Proportional projection of the image
            - Frameclock, A1, A2
        - Evergy convertion
            with function and P1, P2
        - Figure creation
        - Geotiff creation
        - export into file figure, geotiff and numpy file
        """
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':

    paramsGeoRef = []
    for im in imgfiles:
        paramsGeoRef.append([Frameclock, A1, A2, B1, B2, fileName, D1 , D2 , D3 , P1 , P2])
    if flag_parallel:
        cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        cpus = cpus - 1
        pool2 = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpus)
        pool2.map(georef, paramsGeoRef)
        pool2.close()
        pool2.join()
```

**I tried different approaches, such as**:

Unpack arguements before:

```
def star_georef(Frameclock, A1,A2, B1, B2, fileName, D1, D2, D3, P1, P2):
    return georef(*paramsGeoRef)

def georef(paramsGeoRef):
    #Pseudo workflow...
    return None
```

Used another map type:

```
pool2.imap_unordered()
```

What wrong? Why this method work for crunching `numpy` array, but not for this purpose? Need to handle a chunksize?

Maybe, I might need to feed workers as soon as they are available with a job generator?

Comment: I suspect the bottleneck is related to passing the `Frameclock` GB argument to each of the processes. Might be better to make it a `mmap` and pass that  to avoid the overhead that involves (regardless of how much hardware you throw at it).

Comment: I save the Frameclock, A1 and A2 in .npy with numpy. I loaded it in georef instead. Drastic efficiency gain!!! Thanks

Comment: Good to hear — you're welcome.

Comment: Question : Using a memmap (np.memmap) can it even more efficient then a pickle such as.npy ? Specially when you used hundrens of MB ndarray.

Comment: Yes, using a memory map would effectively allow the sharing of the data among the processes — the reason I originally suggested using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Martineau advice,

I save the Frameclock, A1 and A2 arguements with with numpy in .npy format. Then I load the .npy inside the parallelized .

such as :

```
def georef(paramsGeoRef):

    #Pseudo workflow
    """
    - unpack arguments, Frameblock, A1,A2, B1, B2, fileName, D1, D2, D3, P1, P2 <== paramsGeoRef
    - load Frameblock from his .npy
    - load A1 from his .npy
    - load A2 from his .npy
    - Loading tif image
    - Evergy convertion
        with function and P1, P2
    - Proportional projection of the image
        - Frameclock, A1, A2
    - Evergy convertion
        with function and P1, P2
    - Figure creation
    - Geotiff creation
    - export into file figure, geotiff and numpy file
    """
    return None
```

Even with saving and loading these is a drastic efficiency gain! All worker works.